# Redis sentinel cluster in kubernetes, sentinel is not able to reach redis master

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

I am working on creating a Redis sentinel cluster by using below:

https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storage/redis

It's working awesome with the given image, but when we use the Redis official image the sentinel is not able to connect to Redis in the first pod.

It's showing below error:

> Could not connect to redis at -p:6379

How can I create a cluster with the official image of Redis?

Comment: Hi, By official image you mean official docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) of Redis?

Comment: How did You create a cluster with official image?

Comment: Hi piotr,  yes I am using official docker image of redis.

Comment: I m just following above git url and using redis image instead of alpine.

Comment: Did you start sentinel container with --sentinel in your pod? Are you also using a sentinel.conf file that tells it who's master? (monitor master)

Answer (score 0):

To replace image from google repository to public docker hub image the following deployment files need to be modified for this example:

```
examples/staging/storage/redis/redis-master.yaml
examples/staging/storage/redis/redis-sentinel-service.yaml
examples/staging/storage/redis/redis-controller.yaml
```

In those files You will find image configurations like this:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: sentinel
        image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:v1
```

replace all of the `image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:v1` to `image: redis:stable` or  to `image: redis:latest`.

After modyfying those image configurations should look like this:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: sentinel
        image: redis:stable
```

The alpine image in dockerfile You mentioned is used to run scripts in order to Remove trailing whitespaces.

---

**Update:**

Upon further investigation it seems that this example is using specific redis [image](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/redis@sha256:ae4699b8f330d61665125cd381942fc1c57613f2753c5ee6879aff173a8ccb52/details?tab=info) from GCR repository and replacing it with official redis image will not work.

If You want to deploy redis in kubernetes i suggest using [bitnami-docker-redis](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis) github project. More information about installing it on kubernetes can be found [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/upstreamed/redis).

The official [redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis) github page and redis [documentation](https://redis.io/documentation) don't mention anything about deploying redis on kubernetes.

Comment: I already tried above which u mentioned, the issue I am getting is sentinel is not able to connect at port 6379.